# Can the Hunter ability "Animal Focus" be used in conjunction with the spell "Animal Aspect"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

Can a Hunter benefit from both their Animal Focus ability and a casting of the Animal Aspect spell?

They use similar wording, but most of their bonuses are different, with the spell being generally stronger, but with less options. Would it be possible to have both effects active at the same time? The one is a swiftly activated supernatural ability, the other is a standard action spell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Despite the similarities in teminology, the two things are totally separate, and able to be applied to the same creature.